# Recognizing element in an Hybrid App - Android

Tags: selenium, appium

I am new to Android testing. I am currently trying to automate a scenario. I have attached the snapshot of the app screen:

[image]

**Scenario**:

1. I need to click on "Clock In".
2. A screen slides from the bottom as shown in the snapshot.
3. I need to select an item as shown by the arrow.

The developer is saying that it is a Hybrid app. A lot of confusion here for me as I am able to click on "Clock In", but I am not able to select "DL 380 Memory Upgrade".

**Doubts**:

1. How to find whether "DL 380 Memory Upgrade" is in Webview/Native?
2. If it is an element in the webview, how to locate it? I located "CLOCK IN" as below:

   `@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.View[@resource-id='tab-t0-0']")
   private AndroidElement clockInTabBtn;`

Comment: What context are you using now?

Comment: @EugeneS I started using the webview and I was able to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its an element in WebView, then its *web* and you won't find anything in web while searching by *resource-id* - its native attribute only.

I would recommend to use chrome dev tools for debugging hybrid application.
You can read official [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) for setup.

Basically you need:

1. connect device
2. go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome browser
3. check phone & allow usb debugging if popup appears
4. check what webViews chrome spotted and click `inspect` for the one you need
   [image]
5. And now you search for elements and their locators the same way you did in Selenum/Web automation
   [image]
6. Don't forget to **switch context to WebView** in your appium test before you actually searching inside webView.

Good luck!

Comment: @dmie Are there any specific capabilities that I am suppose for testing hybrid app? Anything specific to Chrome?

Comment: Nothing by default: `platformName `, `deviceName`, `app`, `appWaitActivity`, `appWaitPackage` should be enough. However you can set `autoWebview` to true if you want to switch to web view right after on app start

Answer (score 0):

You can check available view using context and can switch to it using follows code:

```
Set<string> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) 
{
System.out.println(contextNames);
//To swicth to webview
if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
driver.context(contextName);
}
}
```

Please refer this thread for similar issue: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7243